# jQuery Full Calendar - Prevent user to add new event on the timeslot which already has an event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

**Scenario:** Lets say **"User-A"** has added a new **"Event-1"** on date-time slot **"17-03-2016 10:00:00 AM"** & **"User-B"** also wants to add **"Event-2"** on the same date-time slot i.e **"17-03-2016 10:00:00 AM"**, here user 2 should not be allowed to add a new event due to an existing event on the same slot.

**Language used:** Asp.net (C#)

Any help shall be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the version 2.20 you will only need to set property:

```
eventOverlap: false
```

in the configuration section of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As Lesmian said, setting the config of the plugin will prevent overlaping events:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },           
        timezone: 'UTC',
        editable: true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        ....
```

That will prevent Overlapping on ALL events, but lets say u want to ovelap some events and others not, you can acomplish this by setting in the event source the "**overlap**" parameter either to true or false:

```
{
    "id": "6",
    "title": "Autum Equinox",
    "start": "2016-03-20 12:00:00",
    "end": null,
    "allDay": true,
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "color": "#ff9f89",
    "textColor": null,
    "overlap": true
},
```